# Python pandas/lists Algorithm Performance

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I've written a short script that takes 2 pandas dataframes, one with latitudes and longitudes of assets in a city and another with latitudes and longitudes of amenities within a city.

The assets dataframe has over >160,000 rows. For the difference amenities (GP services, pharmacies, schools etc) my code will eventually loop through a series of csv files and create dataframes of lats and longs of each location of these amenities.

I am currently iterating through each asset and creating a list of distances from each asset to each amenity using geopy.distance.distance() and aggregating to the minimum value of the distances to each amenity. So for example for a csv file with the locations of 200 pharmacies, I want to find the distance of the closest pharmacy to each of my assets.

At the moment I am using list comprehension (twice). Here is my code:

```
# dataframe of amenity lats and lons
GP_Lats_lons = pd.read_csv('GPHealthCentreClinic.csv', usecols=(['lat', 'long']))

#dataframe of asset lats and lons (using database connection)
assets_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn) 

def get_distance(lat, lon):
    distances = [distance.distance((lat,lon),(x['lat'],x['long'])).km for y, x in GP_Lats_lons.iterrows()]  
    return min(distances)

assets_df['nearest_gp_km'] = [get_distance(x['Latitude'], x['Longitude']) for y, x in assets_df[['Latitude','Longitude']].iterrows()]
```

Does anyone have any ideas in terms of data structures and algorithms how the above code can be optimised? Is list comprehension a good/bad way to do this? Is a lambda function within pd.DataFrame.apply() a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, this is so close to this pandas optimisation article: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6.  In short, you need to vectorise your operations.

Comment: I've answered a few questions like this - the primary optimisation is to reduce the number of permutations / combinations so you are doing fewer operations.  for example rather than check 1 asset against 200 pharmacies can you reduce it to 20 pharmacies

Comment: But what is `distance.distance`? Can it natively process numpy arrays?

Comment: Serge looking at the documentation I don't think it does. I think I'll give the 'haversine' function a try using vectorisation. My implementation has been running for an hour.  :( Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long answer for TLDR;

- use combinations, not permutations to drive set of places that need distance calculation
- using `numba` and *haversine* function is more that 10X faster than `geopy.distance`

#### set up

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
searchendpoint = "https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations"
# get all healthcare facilities in Herefordshire
dfhc = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(requests
                             .get(searchendpoint, params={"PostCode":f"HR{i}","Status":"Active"})
                             .json()["Organisations"]) 
           for i in range(1,10)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
# get geo data for all postcodes associated with healthcare facilities
# API batch restriction of 100 post codes per call
dfgeo = (pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(
    requests.post("http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes", 
               json={"postcodes":dfhc.PostCode.unique().tolist()[i:i+100]}).json(),
    record_path="result")
 for i in range(0, len(dfhc.PostCode.unique()), 100)])
 .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace("result.",""))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .assign(coord=lambda dfa: dfa.longitude.combine(dfa.latitude, lambda x,y: (x,y,)))
)
dfgeo_missed = dfgeo.loc[dfgeo.postcode.isna()]
dfgeo = dfgeo.loc[~dfgeo.postcode.isna()]
```

#### numba / geopy / haversine distance

```
import geopy.distance
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

# a few ways to calculate distance between two (lon,lat) pairs
@jit(nopython=True)
def haversine_jit(x,y):
    # approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0

    s_lat = np.deg2rad(x[0])                    
    s_lng = np.deg2rad(x[1])     
    e_lat = np.deg2rad(y[0])                       
    e_lng = np.deg2rad(y[1])

    d = np.sin((e_lat - s_lat)/2)**2 + \
        np.cos(s_lat)*np.cos(e_lat) * \
        np.sin((e_lng - s_lng)/2)**2

    return 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))

def haversine(x,y):
    # approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6373.0

    s_lat = np.deg2rad(x[0])                    
    s_lng = np.deg2rad(x[1])     
    e_lat = np.deg2rad(y[0])                       
    e_lng = np.deg2rad(y[1])

    d = np.sin((e_lat - s_lat)/2)**2 + \
        np.cos(s_lat)*np.cos(e_lat) * \
        np.sin((e_lng - s_lng)/2)**2

    return 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d))


def geopykm(x,y):
    return geopy.distance.distance(x,y).km
```

#### optimisations

```
import itertools

# optimisation - use just combinations not permuations of locations
dfcombis = (pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(dfgeo.postcode.values, 2))
 .merge(dfgeo.loc[:,["postcode","coord","longitude","latitude"]], left_on=0, right_on="postcode")
 .merge(dfgeo.loc[:,["postcode","coord","longitude","latitude"]], left_on=1, right_on="postcode")
 .drop(columns=[0,1]))

def testit(df, calc=geopykm, col="km"):
    return df.assign(**{col:df.coord_x.combine(df.coord_y, calc)})

%timeit dfx = testit(dfcombis)
%timeit dfx = testit(dfcombis, calc=haversine)
%timeit dfx = testit(dfcombis, calc=haversine_jit)


dfx = testit(dfcombis, calc=haversine_jit, col="km")
```

#### timings

```
1.77 s ± 63.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
280 ms ± 16.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
125 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### usage

```
# a to b is same as b to a,  concat the reverse
# some locations have multiple facilities, include a to a is 0kmn
dfnb = pd.concat([
    dfx.loc[dfx.km.le(10),["postcode_x","postcode_y","km"]],
    dfx.loc[dfx.km.le(10),["postcode_y","postcode_x","km"]].rename(columns={"postcode_x":"postcode_y","postcode_y":"postcode_x"}),
    pd.DataFrame({"postcode_x":dfhc.PostCode.unique(),"postcode_y":dfhc.PostCode.unique(),"km":0})
          ],).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
# finally some analysis,  find nearest pharmacies to GP surgery

(dfnb.merge(dfhc.loc[dfhc.PrimaryRoleId.isin(["RO180","RO96"]),["Name","PostCode","PrimaryRoleDescription"]],
    left_on="postcode_x", right_on="PostCode")
 .merge(dfhc.loc[dfhc.PrimaryRoleId.isin(["RO182","RO177"]),["Name","PostCode","PrimaryRoleDescription"]],
    left_on="postcode_y", right_on="PostCode")
 .sort_values(["Name_x","km"])
 .groupby(["Name_x"], as_index=False).first()

)
```

|  | Name_x | postcode_x | postcode_y | km | PostCode_x | PrimaryRoleDescription_x | Name_y | PostCode_y | PrimaryRoleDescription_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 22A KING STREET | HR4 9DA | HR4 9AA | 0.213861 | HR4 9DA | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR4 9AA | PHARMACY |
| 1 | ALTON STREET SURGERY | HR9 5AB | HR9 5AB | 0 | HR9 5AB | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | ALTON STREET SURGERY | HR9 5AB | PRESCRIBING COST CENTRE |
| 2 | AUBREY STREET | HR4 0BU | HR4 9AA | 0.148447 | HR4 0BU | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR4 9AA | PHARMACY |
| 3 | AYLESTONE HILL SURGERY | HR1 1HR | HR4 9AA | 1.46984 | HR1 1HR | BRANCH SURGERY | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR4 9AA | PHARMACY |
| 4 | BARRS COURT SCHOOL | HR1 1EQ | HR4 9AA | 1.27244 | HR1 1EQ | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR4 9AA | PHARMACY |
| 5 | BELMONT ABBEY | HR2 9RP | HR2 9RP | 0 | HR2 9RP | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | CYPS - LINDEN CENTRE | HR2 9RP | PRESCRIBING COST CENTRE |
| 6 | BELMONT HEALTH CENTRE | HR2 7XT | HR2 7XT | 0 | HR2 7XT | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | BELMONT MEDICAL CENTRE | HR2 7XT | PRESCRIBING COST CENTRE |
| 7 | BLACKMARSTON SCHOOL | HR2 7NX | HR2 7JE | 0.975908 | HR2 7NX | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | ASDA PHARMACY | HR2 7JE | PHARMACY |
| 8 | BOBBLESTOCK SURGERY | HR4 9LP | HR4 9AA | 3.5643 | HR4 9LP | BRANCH SURGERY | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR4 9AA | PHARMACY |
| 9 | BODENHAM SURGERY | HR1 3JU | HR6 8LR | 9.71357 | HR1 3JU | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR6 8LR | PHARMACY |
| 10 | DENTAL ACCESS CENTRE/HEALTH PROMOTION | HR2 7JE | HR2 7JE | 0 | HR2 7JE | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | ASDA PHARMACY | HR2 7JE | PHARMACY |
| 11 | ETNAM STREET MENTAL HEALTH RESOURCE CENTRE | HR6 8AN | HR6 8LR | 0.557963 | HR6 8AN | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | BOOTS UK LIMITED | HR6 8LR | PHARMACY |
| 12 | KINGTON COURT HEALTH AND SOCIAL CARE CENTRE | HR5 3BX | HR5 3BJ | 0.649622 | HR5 3BX | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | KINGTON PHARMACY | HR5 3BJ | PHARMACY |
| 13 | KINGTON SURGERY | HR5 3EA | HR5 3EA | 0 | HR5 3EA | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | KINGTON MEDICAL PRACTICE | HR5 3EA | PRESCRIBING COST CENTRE |